# Swift weak delegate runtime error (bad access). Bug?

Tags: macos, delegates, swift

I have a problem with delegates in Swift (OSX). I have a view, connected to a delegate through a weak reference. Simplified code could be like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func protocolFunc() -> Int
}

class MyController : MyProtocol {
    func protocolFunc() -> Int { return 2 }
}

class MyView : NSView {
    weak var delegate: MyProtocol?

    func grabData {
        var data = delegate?.protocolFunc()
    }
}
```

When `delegate?.protocolFunc()` is called, the app crashes saying "bad access". It's like if the MyController instance had disappeared... But it has not. The MyController instance lives in a NSDocument subclass; and view's delegate is properly set.

The crash goes away if I declare the delegate to be `strong`. But the thing is I want the delegate to be `weak`. What's going on? To my eyes, the weak reference should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing (Xcode 6 Beta 5), there's a bug with weak delegates. For the time being, all you can do until it is fixed is to change `protocol MyProtocol: class` to `@objc protocol MyProtocol` and avoid using any pure Swift classes in your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

A *temporary* alternate solution would be to change this:

```
weak var delegate: MyProtocol?
```

to this:

```
weak var delegate: MyController?
```

Of course it defeats the purpose of MyProtocol, however, it allows you to use pure Swift classes while we wait for a proper fix for this.